# Counting cliques in graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

In graph theory, a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) is an undirected graph in which any pair of distinct vertices is connected by an edge. The *clique number* of an undirected graph $G$ is defined to be the maximal size of a subgraph of $G$ that is a clique. The problem of finding the clique number of a given graph is called the [*Clique problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). It is known that the Clique problem is NP-complete. But could there be a more efficient way to count the exact number of cliques in an arbitrary, given graph?

Edit: Counting cliques of a specific size is [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete). Is it possible to reduce counting cliques of a specific size to counting the overall number of cliques in a graph?

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that once you have a max clique you have a lower bound for the value you're looking for (all the sub-cliques contained in a clique), yet I can't currently think of a way to count multiple cliques of the same order..

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9209/finding-all-cliques-of-a-graph

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell us your definition of a "clique" since the term has been used in the literature with two different meanings: (1) a set of pairwise adjacent vertices, (2) a *maximal* set of pairwise adjacent vertices.

Comment: Counting cliques in a graph is equivalent to counting independent sets in its complement graph. Apparently there is a proof of the fact that counting independent sets is #P-complete in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0212053). I will write an answer once I get around to read it.